# Geek Chic Rail System Dimensions?

Tags: storage

I am working on building my own gaming table and was wondering if anyone could provide me with a detailed set of dimensions for the Geek Chic rail system and a cupholder.

Answer (score 1):

I think the rail designs are pretty clear from this picture off their website.  The exact numbers aren't important if you're building it yourself.

Assuming this desk is 1/2" thick, then the rail groove entrance is roughly 3/8" thick, and the rail is roughly 1/2" deep.  There is a groove going up behind the rail, that looks to be 1/4" wide, that "locks" the desk into place.  Notice, that most of the force of the desk here is getting absorbed not by the thin piece of the desk going into the groove, but the "side wall."

These are beautiful tables!  Good luck with your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building one too and after looking around the internet, I found a lot of good sources and references.

Have a look at this one:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/kyouteki/sets/72157640655268305/

You can see the little upwards groove that John was referring to.

I cut mine at 5/8" deep x 5/8" high (to the high point in the back). I think I have a sketch somewhere if you would like to see it.

Trial and error on cheap wood is you best bet as there is no "correct" dimensions and it all depends on the thickness of the stock you'll be using for your final product.

Cheers,

Hugo